# Check Java Version/API compat in maven without installing old JDKs?

Tags: maven

Is there a way to make sure that maven modules are API-compatible to older Java releases without installing and using the specific JDK release? Ie. some plugin?

Example: java.lang.String.isBlank() is available from JDK 11 only, so the plugin should check whether that method has been used if target version is <=10.

Alternatively, I could write a few plugin executions to download/unpack a jdk and then build the current project against that specific jdk. However, that'd be ugly.

Comment: In cases for JDK9+ you can use `<release>9</release>` option for the maven-compiler-plugin which controls the release switch of the javac.

Comment: For Java 8 and before you can use https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/

Answer (score 0):

the animal sniffer recommendation works great:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>verify-java-api</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <signature>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java18</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </signature>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Update: that animal sniffer configuration did not find this issue:

```
symbol:   variable RELEASE_10
location: class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
```